# What's the difference between Celery GroupResult and ResultSet?

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

The docs only mention that `GroupResult` is "Like [ResultSet](http://Like%20ResultSet,%20but%20with%20an%20associated%20id.), but with an associated id."

Specifically, when would it be suitable to use `ResultSet` instead of `GroupResult` if the only difference is `GroupResult` has an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use ResultSet when you have multiple AsyncResult objects from *different tasks* that you want to deal with all at once. GroupResult on the other hand is what you use instead of AsyncResult when you executed the [Group](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#groups) primitive and want to query what is happening with the tasks in the group. That is why it has an associated ID - because the Group will have a task-id associated to it.